# Angular js : Array

Tags: angularjs

i have this json retrieve from Rest Api jsonconfig:

```
$scope.setPolygone = function (id)
    {

        console.log(spotcam.jsonconfig);
        $scope.DrawPolygon(id, JSON.parse(spotcam.jsonconfig), true);
       }
```

Comment: So  your final question is to modify array ?

Comment: hello my question is how i can modify the content of json[x , y] by the content of array

Comment: so you want the json to finally look like this?  "polygon": [{
        "P1": {
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0
        },
        "P2": {
            "x": 150,
            "y": 0
        }, .......

Comment: yes declanMcd i need this

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a logical implementation from my side. Loop through each object in the array. Keep a local index as well and replace the x, y values in the data array.

```js
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        "polygon": [{
            "P1": { "x": 165, "y": 257 },
            "P2": { "x": 573, "y": 200 },
            "P3": { "x": 441, "y": 463 },
            "P4": { "x": 20,  "y": 463 }
        }]
    }
    $scope.DEFAULT_POLYGONS_POINTS = [ [0, 0], [150, 0], [150, 150], [0, 150]];
    let index = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.data.polygon[0], function(value, key){
        value.x = $scope.DEFAULT_POLYGONS_POINTS[index][0];
        value.y = $scope.DEFAULT_POLYGONS_POINTS[index][1];
        ++index;
     });

    console.log($scope.data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you and how i can change  my function  set polygon please

Comment: @sani what are _GetSpotCAMFromId and $scope.DrawPolygon, methods? What is $scope.selectedSpotCAM?

Comment: how i can do in just  $scope.DrawPolygon(id, JSON.parse(spotcam.jsonconfig), true);

Comment: What is the desired output of $scope.DrawPolygon(id, JSON.parse(spotcam.jsonconfig), true); method? I think u can build it yourself.

Comment: i ddon't need to change JSON.parse(spotcam.jsonconfig) ?